# Need to add a page overlay in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a function that changes the cursor to "waiting" when you click on a radio box because the page needs to reload.  I would also like to add an overlay and have the page be "grayed" out when they click on the radio button.  Could anyone help me add an overlay to this function? Or would I need an entirely new function?

```
     function setHourglass()
     {
       document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use css filter methods and a bit of JQuery:

```
  function setHourglass()
     {
       document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
       $('body').css({
         'filter':'grayscale(100%)',
         '-webkit-filter':'grayscale(100%)'
       });
     }
```

to get it back use:

```
filter: grayscale(0%)
```

i hope this will solve your problems

[You can read more about CSS filter here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/)

Comment: This just makes my page hang.

Comment: and what console says?

Comment: if page hangs there is problem with script. Did you add jquery library in html? Maybe you've made a typo? it is 4 lines of code, check if everything is correct and give me a feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

For what you need I will go with doing everything by css and pure javascript, without needing jQuery.

First of all let's update a bit your function :

```
    function setHourglass(){
        // Cache HTML tag
        var page = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
        // Add a custom class when the function is called
        page.className = 'wait'; 
    }
```

And handeling the class wait with css you can do everything you need :

```
.wait {
    cursor: wait;
}

.wait body:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
    content: '';
    /*background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
    /*Alternative for what we have below*/
    background: #000;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xfbszhmj/)

Comment: The cursor seems to work, but there is no overlay still.

Comment: It's probably something incompatible on my end.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Put more code or show me an screenshot. As you can see in fiddle, it works so maybe there are any other things